# Is there any other way to remove an element in a list besides knowing its actual value?

Tags: ruby, redis

**Value edits at the bottom.**

I would prefer a more robust solution. The following is a very hacky approach.

Suppose the following:

```
Redis.rpush("list_of_objs", ['{"value": 1, "id: 3}', '{"value": 2, "id": 9}', 
'{"value": 8, "id": 1}', '{"value": 9, "id": 99}', '{"value": 10, "id": 1252}', 
'{"value": 0, "id": 99999}']).
```

I now have a list of simple json objects that only have value and id attributes.

If you're curious,

```
Redis.lrange("list_of_objs", 0, -1)
#=> ['{"value": 1, "id: 3}', '{"value": 2, "id": 9}', '{"value": 8, "id": 1}', '{"value": 9, "id": 99}', '{"value": 10, "id": 1252}', '{"value": 0, "id": 99999}']
```

Awesome. Now, let us assume we want to delete `'{"value": 8, "id": 1}'`. That is achieved through the following command:

```
Redis.lrem("list_of_objs", 1, '{"value": 8, "id": 1}')
```

If you call `Redis.lrange("list_of_objs", 0, -1)` once more, you'll now see that we successfully deleted the element.

This works *in some cases*, but truth be told, in many cases, this isn't sufficient. I'm not guaranteed that what I want to delete will be exactly the same since when I put it into the list. Someone may choose to change `'{"value": 8, "id": 1}'` to `'{"value": 22, "id": 1}'` before I decide to delete it. However, if I try to delete it now, I'm screwed. The same command won't work. Now, if we used some Ruby logic, we could easily get this sorted, but the solution becomes rather **hacky** if you ask me.

Now, the assumption with this type of solution is that some element within your object, in our case the `id`, stays the same throughout the lifetime of the object.

Now, the solution:

```
Redis.multi do
  array = Redis.lrange("list_of_objs", 0, -1)
  index_of_element_to_be_destroyed = array.index { |el| JSON.parse(el)["id"] == 1 }
  element = Redis.lindex("list_of_objs", index_of_element_to_be_destroyed)
  Redis.lrem("list_of_objs", 1, element)
end
```

That seems a bit hacky to have to delete 1 element. I'm pretty sure by doing it in `multi`, I'm safe from the index potentially changing via something concurrent.

Edit 1: Actually, I'm pretty sure the above might not even work. I'm not sure if I am allowed to do such ruby like `array.index` in a `Redis.multi` block.

Edit 2: Perhaps I do the deletion in Ruby, then just re-`rpush` the array? I would like to avoid that.

Edit 3: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300958/how-can-i-read-from-redis-inside-a-multi-block-in-ruby) seems to hold valuable information, but if I'm seriously expected to use a `loop` and `watch`, then I think this is much more hacky than I anticipated.

That being said, is there a better way to delete an element in a list based on some condition?

Comment: Would you consider using a different layout for your data? There are other solutions that don't rely on a list, let me know and I will suggest one of them.

Comment: why don't you use the hash datastructure instead of the list?

Comment: @soveran I would definitely consider a different lay-out for my data. New to Redis, and at the time, a list seemed to make the most sense.

Comment: Do the items have only id and value? Will they hold other fields?